# Scala 2.11 compilation for the Apache Bahir Library

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-bahir

Not sure if this is the right place to post this question. (Apologies if it isn't. And if so, please point me in the right direction.)

I am attempting to compile [Apache Bahir](https://github.com/apache/bahir) to generate scala 2.11 artifacts (as `mvn clean install -P scala-2.11 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests`). When attempting do so, I am running into the following build issues:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Apache Bahir - Parent POM 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Parent POM .......................... SUCCESS [ 4.166 s]
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Common .............................. SUCCESS [ 20.276 s]
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark SQL Cloudant DataSource ....... FAILURE [ 0.147 s]
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark SQL Streaming Akka ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark SQL Streaming MQTT ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark SQL Streaming JDBC ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark SQL Streaming SQS ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark Streaming Akka ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark Streaming MQTT ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark Streaming PubNub .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark Streaming Google PubSub ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark Streaming Twitter ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Bahir - Spark Streaming ZeroMQ .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.877 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-07T18:42:46-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spark-sql-cloudant_2.12: Could not resolve
 dependencies for project org.apache.bahir:spark-sql-cloudant_2.12:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.bahir:bahir-common_2.11:jar:3.0.0-
SNAPSHOT, org.apache.bahir:bahir-common_2.11:jar:tests:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find 
org.apache.bahir:bahir-common_2.11:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR] mvn <args> -rf :spark-sql-cloudant_2.12
```

Upon examining the `common/target` directory, I see that although there is a `scala-2.11` sub-directory with compiled class files in there, I don't see the appropriate `bahir-common_2.11-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT*.jar` files being generated (while the `bahir-common_2.12-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT*.jar` seem to be generated just fine).

I was wondering if anyone here could potentially help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is one way to do it(?):

```
$ cd <project_root_dir>
$ ./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11
$ mvn clean package -Pscala-2.11 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTest
```

PS: If anyone has an authoritative answer to this, please chime in. Thanks!